# weird output of counter variable in comparator java

Tags: java, oop, collections, comparator

I wrote a piece of code to learn more about `Comparator` function of java collection. I have two sets having 3 elements in each. and i want to compare.
I post my code below and output of counter variable. Can anyone explain why variable `i` gives this weird output ?? I could not understand flow.

```
public class TestProductBundle {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    TestProductBundle productBundle = new TestProductBundle();

    Set<ClassA> hashSetA = new HashSet<ClassA>() {
        {
            add(new ClassA("name", 1, "desc"));
            add(new ClassA("name", 2, "desc"));
            add(new ClassA("name", 3, "desc"));
        }
    };

    Set<ClassA> hashSetB = new HashSet<ClassA>() {
        {
            add(new ClassA("name1", 2, "desc1"));      //"name" & "desc" are different than previous 
            add(new ClassA("name2", 1, "desc2"));
            add(new ClassA("name3", 3, "desc3"));
        }
    };

    if (productBundle.compareCollection(hashSetA, hashSetB)) {
        System.out.println("Equal set of tree");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unequal set of tree");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public boolean compareCollection(Set<ClassA> collection1, Set<ClassA> collection2) {

    TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetA = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID()) {
        {
            addAll(collection1);
        }
    };

    TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetB = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID()) {
        {
            addAll(collection2);
        }
    };

    if (treeSetA.containsAll(treeSetB) && treeSetB.containsAll(treeSetA))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

code for ClassA and class that implements Comparator.

```
class ClassA {
String name;
int id;
String desc;

public ClassA(String name, int id, String desc) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.desc = desc;
}

int getId() {
    return id;
    }
}
```

&

```
class CompareID implements Comparator<ClassA> {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public int compare(ClassA o1, ClassA o2) {
        System.out.println(i++);                   // Counter variable
        if (o1.getId() > o2.getId())
            return 1;
        else if (o1.getId() < o2.getId())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;

    }
}
```

output is (cross verified in debugger also)

```
0
1
2
3
0   // why started from 0 again ?
1      
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
4   // What the hell !!!
5
6
7
8
Equal set of tree  // is that correct output ?
```

Comment: what would you expect there to make it not look weird?

Comment: I do not have clue why it starts from 4 after 8, also 0 after 3.

Comment: Again, what do you expect to see? How is what you are seeing different to what you expect to see? Nice details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are finding strange.
You have **two** TreeSet instances, each having its own `CompareID` instance serving as `Comparator`, and each `CompareID` instance maintains it's own counter.

Therefore it's not a surprise to see each counter values (0,1,2,etc...) appearing twice.
As for the order of appearance of the counter values, that depends on the internal implementation of `TreeSet`.

As for

> Equal set of tree  // is that correct output ?

Yes, both sets contain the same elements. The order doesn't matter.
To clarify - the methods `contains` and `containsAll` of `TreeSet` consider an element `x` to be contained in the `TreeSet` if `compare(x,y)==0` for some element `y` of the `TreeSet`, where `compare` is the `compare` method of the supplied `Comparator`. Therefore, in your example, only the `id` property determines if two elements are equal.

The following scenario explains the output :

```
0 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
1 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
2 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
3 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
0 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
1 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed      
2 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
3 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
4 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
5 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
6 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
7 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
8 // compare method of 1st CompareID object executed
4 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
5 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
6 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
7 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
8 // compare method of 2nd CompareID object executed
```

EDIT : First you are adding elements to the first `TreeSet` (hence `compare` of the first `Comparator` is called several times in a row), then you are adding elements to the second `TreeSet` (hence `compare` of the second `Comparator` is called several times in a row), then you call `treeSetA.containsAll(treeSetB)` which causes `compare` of the first `Comparator` to be called several times in a row, and finally you call `treeSetB.containsAll(treeSetA)` which causes `compare` of the second `Comparator` to be called several times in a row.

Comment: What about '4' after '8' ?

Comment: "Yes, both sets contain the same elements. The order doesn't matter."   ----> Elements are different, look at name and description from second set please.

Comment: @user3042916 They are the same elements as far as the Comparator is concerned, since it only cares about the id property.

Answer (score 1):

Here Variable i will be initialize for two comparator object , your are initializing i=0, as per your point here compare method  will be executed for both sets not necessary to be in sequence, so whats happen is you are expecting sequence output but actually its not

```
0// for set1(collection1)
1
2
3  // remember this value for set 1
0   // for set2(collection2)
1      
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
4   for set1(collection1 which was 3 and now increment to 1 )
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Erans answer.

Change the code to the following and you´ll see which comperator does output when

```
class CompareID implements Comparator<ClassA> {
    int i = 0;
    String a;
    public CompareID(String input) {
        a = input;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(ClassA o1, ClassA o2) {
        // Output comperator "id"
        System.out.println(a+ "   "  + i++); // Counter variable
        if (o1.getId() > o2.getId())
            return 1;
        else if (o1.getId() < o2.getId())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;

    }
}

... 

    TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetA = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID("A")) {
        {
            addAll(collection1);
        }
    };

    TreeSet<ClassA> treeSetB = new TreeSet<ClassA>(new CompareID("B")) {
        {
            addAll(collection2);
        }
    };
```

The output will change to the following. The comments include what did produce the output:

```
// This is addALL treeSetA
A   0
A   1
A   2
A   3
// this is addAll treeSetB
B   0
B   1
B   2
B   3
// this is treeSetA.containsAll(treeSetB)
A   4
A   5
A   6
A   7
A   8
// this is treeSetB.containsAll(treeSetA)
B   4
B   5
B   6
B   7
B   8
```

basicly both comperators just output

```
0-8
0-8
```

Comment: I am curious, Can you explain me why it is not synchronised ?

Comment: @user3042916 i did edit it, missinterpreted something there, the comment in the output should help now ;)